# Remove Rails partial from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

My Rails app uses partials to load different pieces of the site into view. I'd like to add a close icon that removes the partial from view when clicked. Example: The user opens a folder in the app, and clicks an icon to "close" the folder. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The rendered page no longer knows what a partial is, but if you wrap your partials in uniquely id'ed `div` elements, you can use javascript in the `onclick` event to hide or show the `div`.

Comment: Have you considered using something like jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: Seems obvious now. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Also, if the partial is reused multiple times on the page, you can't get away with unique IDs - use a class on your partial and you can use jQuery to get the `.parent(".partial-class")` of your close button, and work from that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok quick solution with jquery:

_partial.html.erb

```
<div id="unique">
 <p>Html code here</p>
</div>
```

View.html.erb

```
    <%= render :partial => 'partial' %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () { 
        $('#unique').remove()
      }
    </script>
```

removing the DOM node with jquery .remove()
http://api.jquery.com/remove/